# Removing event handlers in c#

Tags: c#, events

I'm working on a Windows Forms app and I've come to a point where I can't understand what's happening.

I have something similar to an MVC architecture. Sometimes I want controls that belong to the view to stop listening to events. So inside the view code I've written a method that looks like this:

```
public void enableEventHandlers(bool enable)
{
    if (enable)
    {
        control.someEvent += someEventHandler;
    }
    else
    {
        control.someEvent -= someEventHandler;
    }
}
```

The thing is: when I want to remove an event handler I just call this method with false as a parameter.
If I call this method from inside the view code it works just fine. But if I call this method from inside the controller code, it doesn't work (the event handlers are not removed).

Just to give a little more context:

This works:

```
public partial class View : Form
{
     public void enableEventHandlers(bool enable)
     {
         // The code I already showed
     }

     public void doSomething()
     {
         enableEventHandlers(false);
         // do something
         enableEventHandlers(true);
     }
 }
```

This doens't work:

```
public class controller
{
     private View myView;

     public void doSomething()
     {
         myView.enableEventHandlers(false);
         // Do something... but somehow everything inside my Form is still paying attention to events
         myView.enableEventHandlers(true);
     }
}
```

Comment: this isn't a threading problem? All GUI code must be called from the main thread. Is your controller on a different thread?

Comment: Since your code actually looks as if it should do what you want, I think we need some more context. Can you try to create a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Additionally, you could check that the event handler is actually registered prior to trying to remove it. Same goes for adding a handler. Ensure that there's no handler currently registered. Also, your form is a partial class. Check that the initialization code isn't registering an event handler. Better to avoid using the Designer altogether for WinForms dev. Just create a class that subclasses Form and write the code yourself. You'll have far better control over your end product. You should also consider your UI design. If you're having to remove handlers like this, it's probably wrong.

Comment: What is your 'control' object and where are you creating instances of these?

Comment: You don't happen to be doing anything asynchronously do you? That could cause issues.

Comment: @RenéVogt Thanks for the advice. I've just written a mini example and it works as it should... I mean.. it does what I want it to do. I'll keep touching my project code and if I find what's causing problems I'll post an update. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the problem. It seems that somehow I was attaching an event handler twice to the same Control. I couldn't find the exact line number where I was doing that anyway. The solution I found is to remove an event handler before adding a new one.
So the method enableEventHandlers looks now like this:

```
public void enableEventHandlers(bool enable) {
    if (enable)
    {
        control.someEvent -= someEventHandler;
        control.someEvent += someEventHandler;
    }
    else
    {
        control.someEvent -= someEventHandler;
    } 
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if that's it but you didn't initialize your View. You just say "private View view", but that doesn't point to anywhere. You want to either make a new View by doing private View v = new View(), or let that view point to the view that you want to change the events.

Comment: So he would have caught a `NullReferenceException`, which I'm sure he would have told us about.